# Configure lambda customer input retries

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-lex

1. Looping of the prompt is happening whenever no answer is given by the user for more than 3 times.

Hi. I am trying to limit the times that a slot prompt is prompted  to 3. When it reaches its limit with no answer, close the chat

In the Lex configuration for the slot I set the retries to 3 but as I connected a lambda function, that does not work. Can someone help me out on this?